# free() and then malloc() again

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

I'm having difficulties reducing the memory allocated by a pointer. This is done as this pointer points to a char array which will store bytes but the number of bytes can differ.

The following struct is used:

```
struct packet {
   unsigned char *data
}
```

In my code, I first allocate memory for the packet and data:

```
struct packet *pack;
pack = malloc(sizeof(struct packet));
pack->data = malloc(MAXSIZE);
```

MAXSIZE is the maximum size that will be read at once (256 bytes).

After reading the file with a buffer and setting the data to the buffer using: `pack->data= &buffer`, I read the remaining bytes in the file (calculated using stat() and subtracting MAXSIZE each time until we have less than MAXSIZE left.)

At this point, I want to make the data pointer allocate less memory than MAXSIZE as the data will not be as large, I try the following code but it fails and results in "core dumped":

```
free(pack->data);
printf("Memory freed.") // This never gets printed so there is an issue with free...
pack->data = malloc(remaining_size);
```

The remaining_size is calculated correctly so I know it should allocate correctly. Am I taking the wrong approach? I've also tried `realloc()` but I get the same result.

Would really appreciate some help, this is a general problem but I need something similar to work for a school project requiring all memory to be freed. If I can solve this issue, I should be able to free the memory. Thanks!

Edit: If I remove the free() call and simply malloc() again, it works but I believe this is the wrong approach as the old allocated space is gone forever and I can never free it.

Comment: `pack->payload = &buffer` did you mean `data` instead of `payload` or does your packet struct actually have two members?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to use data instead of payload. payload is a pointer used for our project but I was trying to make this question more general as I still hope to learn from the project instead of simply getting an answer.

Comment: Maybe put a `printf` before the free so we can be sure it is about free? It would be about `pack->data` more likely than `free`. Maybe somewhere in the code you change the value of the pointer to something else.

Comment: `pack->data= &buffer` Didn't you just destroy the pointer you got with `pack->data = malloc(MAXSIZE);`? That line doesn't copy the contents of buffer into `pack->data`, it overwrites the pointer.

Comment: It seems likely that either `pack->data` is getting corrupted or you have a buffer overrun in the memory it points to. Carefully examine the code between the `malloc` and the `free`. Use a memory debugger such as valgrind if you can.

Comment: If I put the 'printf' before the free, even that doesn't get printed, odd... But if I comment out free, it works.

Comment: @Abubakr: That's probably due to output buffering.

Comment: 'char buffer[256];' and it is being fed using 'fread(&buffer,...)'. Should I be directly using 'pack->data = buffer'?

Comment: Also keep in mind memory fragmentation. `malloc` for data structures with size equal to one pointer is a bit too much. Use local variable instead.

Comment: You probably want to `fread(pack->data, ...)`. Either that or `memcpy(pack->data, buffer, ...)`

Comment: @Abubakr - if you want to use printf() in such a circumstance, make sure there is a \n at the end of the string. This will flush the buffer so that it gets printed before something after crashes the program. (You could also follow the printf() with fflush(stdin).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
pack->data = &buffer;
```

After executing that line, `data` will hold the address of the variable `buffer`. It will no longer hold the address on the heap that it previously held (and that address is now leaked if you don't hold onto it somewhere else). However `free` only works with addresses on the heap, so calling `free` on `pack->data` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah. Makes a lot of sense, thanks. 'char buffer[256];' and it is being fed using 'fread(&buffer,...)'. Should I be directly using 'pack->data = buffer'?

Comment: Ok, simply using 'pack->data = buffer' seems to work. Thanks! I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Abubakr That would still be undefined behavior for the exact same reason. You're only allowed to use `free` on the result of `malloc` and neither `buffer` nor `&buffer` are the result of `malloc`. I have no idea why it would seem to work. What you should be doing is to just `fread` into `pack->data`.

Comment: Would it also be OK if I used 'memcpy(pack->data, buffer,...)'? I was using 'fread()' on a buffer because I always read MAXSIZE but the final read might be a lower size. At the end, I create another 'char remaining[remaining_size]' and then 'memcpy' buffer to that and then set 'pack->data=remaining'. 

I guess using 'memcpy' would be better as I can see the same error happening.

Comment: It seems to work fine using 'memcpy' instead but I might be missing another potential issue as I did last time.

Comment: @Abubakr: You might want to wait until after the `fread` to do the `malloc`, then use the result of `fread` as the size you allocate and `memcpy`. Then every allocation is perfectly sized.